# Commutative Property of an Operation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that two binary operations, denoted by # and @ , are defined on a nonempty set S, and that the following conditions are satisfied for all x, y, and z in S:

(1) $x \# y$ and $x @ y$ are in $S$.

(2) $x\#(y\#z) = (x\#y)\#z$ and $x@(y@z) = (x@y)@z$.

(3) $x\#y = y\#x$

Also, for each $x$ in $S$ and for each positive integer $n$, the elements $nx$ and $x^n$ are defined recursively as
follows:

- $1x = x^1 = x$ and,
- for integer $k$, if $kx$ and $x^k$ have been defined, then $(k+1)x = (kx)\#x$ and $x^{k+1}= x^k@x$.

Which of the following must be true?

I. $(x@y)^n = x^n@y^n$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $S$ and for each positive integer $n$.

II. $n(x\#y) = nx\#ny$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $S$ and for each positive integer $n$.

III. $x^m@x^n = x^{m+n}$ for each $x$ in $S$ and for all positive integers $m$ and $n$.

(A) I only

(B) II only

(C) III only

(D) II and III only

(E) I, II, and III

The textbook says II and III are true (i.e. option D) and I is not since it fails whenever $@$ is not commutative. But I don't see how that happens. I Will appreciate it if somebody can help me throw more light on that.

Comment: We want to derive facts about the operation using $\textit{only}$ the axioms given: $xyxy \neq xxyy$ unless we know $xy=yx$.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the recursive definitions can be summarised as: $kx = \underbrace{x\#\cdots\#x}_{k\text{ terms}}$ and $x^k = \underbrace{x@\cdots@x}_{k\text{ terms}}$

So $(x@y)^n = (x@y)@\cdots@(x@y)$ while $x^n@y^n= (x@\cdots @x)~@~(y@\cdots @y)$ and we cannot establish that these are equal unless we can "collect like terms".   To do so would require $@$ to be commutative: $x@y=y@x$, and that is not one of the axioms given for the structure of $(S,\#,@)$.

On the other hand, since $\#$ is commutative, then: $n(x\#y) ~{= (x\#y)\#\cdots\#(x\#y) \\= (x\#\cdots\#x)\#(y\#\cdots\#y) \\= nx~\#~ny}$ .

Likewise $x^n@x^m = x^{n+m}$ is readily seen.

Comment: @ Graham Kemp. I think that is where I missed it. I need to be sure the operation is commutative before I collect like terms because collecting like terms is more or less re-arranging what I have in order to suit my need (x before y and vice versa). And since it is not stated (or implied) in the question that the operation is commutative, I should just kind of assume it is not and not re-arrange what I have. I assumed too much, almost taking the operation @ as a multiplication operation in disguised form. Thanks.